# How to achieve semi-perfect matches of fields in Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am trying to devise a duplication catching scheme for my Lucene.net app. My problem is it is hard to make a unique key since many of the fields will be the same. The only fields that I know will be different are the Title and Abstract fields. The problem with making a key from this is someone could  slightly change the title and it would be viewed as unique also. Basically I am looking for a way of having a threshold where if they 95% match it is a match. Is there a way of doing this with Lucene?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unclear about your requirement for a unique key, but you can check out Lucene's FuzzyQuery for matching on similar terms. Check out these articles: [Fuzzy Searches](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/2_9_1/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches), [FuzzyQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_2_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/FuzzyQuery.html).

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you avoid using terms like "n*zis" on StackOverflow.

Comment: I did not use such phrasing at all